# Updating store from 2.5.1 to 3, can i copy DB tables to keep them in synch?

Tags: expresso-store

I just updated Store from 2.5.1 to 3.0.1
Now since this has been done on a separate server, the orders database is out of synch. Can i just copy the tables from the live website to the new website?
And which tables would that exactly be?

Thanks in advance

jelle

Comment: Hi Jelle. Did you work out what tables you needed to move? I need to do something similar. Looking at the database I'm assuming it is: 'exp_store_orders', 'exp_store_order_items', 'exp_store_order_history' & 'exp_store_order_adjustments' - but did you find any others that were required please?

Comment: Wellin the end i ended up updating aadons and EE on a copy, to see what kind of errors i'd encounter. wrote everything down and took the live site offline for a day and redid the process on the live site